# `not a git repository` when following install instructions for picom (a compton fork)

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, compton, picom

I'm trying to install [Picom](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Picom) compositor on Ubuntu and have installed all the dependencies but when I get to the "To Build" section of the guide of [GitHub](https://github.com/yshui/picom) I have to run three commands:

```
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ meson --buildtype=release . build
$ ninja -C build
```

None of which seem to work. Running the first returns...

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

So I tried making my own picom folder, running `git init`. This gets me to command number two which fails, responding with:

```
ERROR: Neither directory contains a build file meson.build.
```

I feel like I'm giving the order to build with bricks that I have yet to download. I would appreciate if someone could point to where I have gone wrong or how I might better troubleshoot my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to clone the repository i.e bring the code at the github to your computer and you can continue. So run these commands.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/yshui/picom.git
$ cd picom
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ meson --buildtype=release . build
$ ninja -C build
```

Comment: I don't know how I was struggling with this. Thank you, I think I need a break from staring at the screen.